# Iterating over array elements asynchronously

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to iterate asynchronously over list of array elements, but with this code:

```js
const calculate = async ({ id, priority, database, product }) => {
    let list_of_products;
    if (priority) {
        list_of_products = await getPriorityList(database, id);
    }
    else {
        const prods = product.split(',');
        await prods.forEach((prod) => {
            list_of_products = getList(database, prod);
            console.log({ list_of_products });
        });
    }
};
```

I get the following `console.log()`:

```
{ list_of_products : Promise { <pending> } }
```

And of course, an error gets thrown eventually.

What is the best practice to handle async calls when iterating? The `getList()` method is async as well.

Comment: You don't need to use async loop. You can just use Promise.all() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: There are many answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: `.forEach()` should be stricken from any use with promises as it is not promise-aware.  Use a regular `for` loop instead and then you can `await` the promise that `getList()` returns.

Comment: Note that `await prods.forEach(...)`  is pointless because `.forEach()` has no return value so you're doing `await undefined` which does nothing useful.  `await` is ONLY useful when you are awaiting a promise.

Answer (score 2):

do not use async await in forEach loops. `await prods.forEach((prod)`. instead of `forEach` loop you can use `for...of` loop.
checkout this: [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

you need to add `await` keyword in front of your `getList(database, prod)`.
otherwise, that async function will return a promise.

I refactored your code.

```
const calculate = async ({ id, priority, database, product }) => {
    let list_of_products;
    if (priority) {
        list_of_products = await getPriorityList(database, id);
    }
    else {
        const prods = product.split(',');
        for(let prod of prods) {
            list_of_products = await getList(database, prod);
            console.log({ list_of_products });
        }
    }
};
```